# Spike trick possibility

Tags: probability

I guess that you all have seen this magic trick where the magician is having 4 plastic cups turned upside-down where one of them contains a spike (bellow the cup). Then the magician asks someone from the audience watching to mix the caps and at the end asks that person to guess which one does not contain the spike in order to hit it with his/her palm. The idea is that although s/he hits 3 cups, the spike is always on the last one. A video is here: [Magic spike trick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdHGoOWrMq8).

What is the possibility of hitting the spike eventually?
I have calculated that it is 1/4 in the 1st try, then 1/3 in the 2nd and 1/2 in the last. Adding them up 1/4 + 1/3 + 1/2 ends up being 108%.
Such a possibility (over 100%) seems wrong. Where is my mistake?

Also, if I see if from a different perspective, I calculate that the possibility of not hitting the spike is:

1st try: 3/4

2nd try: 2/3

3rd try: 1/2

Total: (3/4)*(2/3)*(1/2) which is 25%.
If that is correct in that case, then the possibility of hitting the spike is 100% - 25% = 75%
A number that seems more logical (in the range 0-100%).

Can someone let me know what is wrong with my reasoning on the 1st case?
I am almost 100% sure I am correct in the 2nd case but I am too blind to find my reasoning mistake in the 1st one... :( Because for me the possibility of hitting the spike is the addition of the 3 individual tries.

Comment: Just a small note. You are using the term possibility instead of probability( maybe due to a mistake in translation like I used to). Possibility is a possible event that can happen. Probability of an event is how likely it is for this event to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your answer is not $75\%$ for hitting a spike and $25\%$ for not hitting a spike then you have the wrong answer

Take your first try:

- You are correct that the probability that you hit a spike on the first attempt is $\frac14$
- If you do not hit a spike on the first attempt (probability $1-\frac14=\frac34$) then the conditional probability of hitting a spike on the second attempt is $\frac13$.  So the unconditional probability of hitting a spike on the second attempt is $\frac34 \times \frac13=\frac14$
- If you do not hit a spike on the first or second attempt (probability $1-\frac14-\frac14=\frac12$) then the conditional probability of hitting a spike on the third  attempt is $\frac12$.  So the unconditional probability of hitting a spike on the third  attempt is $\frac12 \times \frac12=\frac14$
- Since these are mutually exclusive events, that makes the probability of hitting a spike on any of the first three attempts $\frac14+\frac14+\frac14=\frac34$

Now take your second try:

- You need to combine the conditional probabilities of missing three times which are $\frac34$, $\frac23$ and $\frac12$
- So the probability of not hitting a spike on any of the first three attempts is $\frac34 \times \frac23 \times \frac12 = \frac14$

Comment: So in my first try the mistake I was doing is that there was some kind of condition that in subsequent tries the spike should not have been hit and as such we must multiply the prior probability of the not hitting condition with the probability of the current attempt... 8)

Comment: More or less, though the condition is that the spike was not hit on *previous* attempts

Answer (score 0):

In your first try, the chance of hitting the spike the second time is $\frac 14$, not $\frac 13$.  If you hit it the first time, you will not hit it the second time, so the chance you will hit it the second time is $\frac 34$ (that you did not hit it the first time) times $\frac 13$ (that you hit it the second time) $=\frac 14$.  Similarly, the chance at the beginning that you will hit it the third time is $\frac 14$, as is the chance for the fourth.

In your second try, $\frac 34 \cdot \frac 23 \cdot \frac 12=\frac 14,$ not $9.3\%$, which agrees with my calculation for the first try.